Can i take the reciprocal of both sides of an equation?
I have the following equation, which i am supposed to solve for $s_{0,4}$:
$$P=\frac{C}{1+s_{0,1}}+\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,2})^2}+\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,3})^3}+\frac{C+F}{(1+s_{0,4})^4}$$
which I rearranged in the following steps :
1.
$$
P-\frac{C}{1+s_{0,1}}-\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,2})^2}-\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,3})^3}=\frac{C+F}{(1+s_{0.4})^4}
$$
2.
$$
\frac{P-\frac{C}{1+s_{0,1}}-\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,2})^2}-\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,3})^3}}{C+F}=\frac{1}{(1+s_{0.4})^4}
$$
My question is if could just take the reciprocal of both sides and turn the equation into this
$$\frac{C+F}{P-\frac{C}{1+s_{0,1}}-\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,2})^2}-\frac{C}{(1+s_{0,3})^3}}=(1+s_{0.4})^4$$
which would then be easily solvable for $s_{0,4}$

What happens when you try to prove it?  Assume $A=B$.  Deduce that $1/A = 1/B$.

That's not what you're doing though - you're pushing the $\frac{C}{1+s_{0,k}}$ terms to the LHS first,  and then taking the reciprocals.
